Can you cure zombie villagers underground with torches?
I cured zombie villagers before. I am not sure, but I am almost certain I have done it before: can you cure zombie villagers underground with torches?

Never heard about that, so I guess it's false. Even the official wiki doesn't say anything about that.
The only way to cure a zombie villager is:

a splash/lingering potion or arrow of Weakness
weakened zombie villager must then be healed by using a golden apple


Note: Placing Beds and Iron Bars around the Zombie Villager speeds up the process (which is why hidden basements in igloos have iron bars)
